# How to go back to the first slide unsing JQuery scrollleft and scrollright

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I want to make div slider using JQuery, but I don't know how to go back to first slide.
This div slider is not automatic slider. It is manual slider.
When you click 'Prev' and 'Next' button, you can move one div back and forth.
What I want to do is when I reach the last div, when I click the 'Next' button, I want to move to the first div, so users can start again.
I got 11 divs and each width is 240, total 2640 px, so if I click the 'Prev' button to go back to the first, it takes some time.

Here is my code.
$(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('#next').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.div-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=240'}, 'slow');        
        });

        $('#prev').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.div-container').animate({scrollLeft:'-=240'}, 'slow');        
        });

    });
```

Please advise me.
Thanks.